# How to put 2 different projects inside one APK

Tags: java, android, unity-game-engine

I have a project which is I built 2 games using Unity, then I exported the games as android projects, so now the problem

I want to make an Android application when you start it you can choose which game you want to play then start playing.

is it possible to do that in android?

**Note** the 2 unity games has the same names of files assets, bin..etc

Comment: Why do you need two different games in one app? In this case, this might help: https://medium.com/@davidbeloosesky/embedded-unity-within-android-app-7061f4f473a

Comment: it's a kind of multi-game inside the apk, thank you for the link

Answer (score 0):

Create something like a `Menu` screen with two buttons. After pressing some of them start corresponding game. You can represent every game as a separate module. But it is not good practice to have two different apps or games in one `APK` file. Instead of this read about [product flavors](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants). You can use it to create two different games (in different `APK` files) but in one `AndroidStudio` project. It allows you to reuse all your resources for both (or even more) games.

Comment: the idea for putting 2 games is that trying to build a game with multi-choice to the user just imagine like a steam you open the application then you choose what to download and play, I found something called Deliver on demand, but thank you BTW

Comment: @Ranker what you describe sounds more like a custom launcher/AppStore ... note that the Steam example is quite weak since the Steam app itself barely takes any resources from the hard drive, it doesn't include all available games within the same APK .. this would probably kill most people's disk storage space ;)